# C++ peek() not seeing new line character

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble reading input from a file that I really shouldn't be having on a homework assignment.  I've used very similar code (the only thing that's changed is where values get shoved) on previous a previous assignment.  I've been given a text file with the following input:

```
10
3 6 4 9 0 7 8
8 5 3 7 3 4 -2
5 10 2 8 1 4 1
2 6 -3 1 3 7 1
1 10 -1 2 2 4 -2
10 9 -3 1 3 7 2 5 1
7 3 0 10 1 2 1 8 2
9 6 6 3 4 10 7
4 8 5 1 9 5 6
6 2 4 3 0 9 0
```

The first line is the number of vertexes present for the above graph.  On each line after, the first number is which vertex this is for, the next number is which vertex it is connected to, and the one after is the weight of that edge.  The line repeats vertex, weight until the end of the line (ie, the first line is for vertex 3, it has an edge to 6 with weight 4, an edge to 9 with weight 0, etc.).  I'm using a 1d vector to represent a matrix using row major notation.  The issue I'm having is that my row variable doesn't seem to be updating at all.  Currently, I get the following output from the last line in the while loop that actually plugs the data into the vector.

```
3:  6: 4
3:  9: 0
3:  7: 8
3:  8: 5
3:  3: 7
3:  3: 4
3:  -2: 5
3:  10: 2
3:  8: 1
3:  4: 1
3:  2: 6
3:  -3: 1
3:  3: 7
3:  1: 1
3:  10: -1
3:  2: 2
3:  4: -2
3:  10: 9
3:  -3: 1
3:  3: 7
3:  2: 5
3:  1: 7
3:  3: 0
3:  10: 1
3:  2: 1
3:  8: 2
3:  9: 6
3:  6: 3
3:  4: 10
3:  7: 4
3:  8: 5
3:  1: 9
3:  5: 6
3:  6: 2
3:  4: 3
3:  0: 9
3:  0: 9
```

My row variable seems to be getting stuck as 3, like the input.peek() as the condition for the while loop is never seeing the new line character.  The really confusing part is that on a similar assignment, this chunk of code worked fine to iterate through the input file and stuff things where they were supposed to go.  I'm stumped, so if someone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.  I apologize in advance if I've been too verbose.

My code is below.

```
if(input.is_open()) // making sure the input is open
{
    input >> nodeCount; //Grabbing the number of nodes from the first value of the file

    for(int i = 1; i < nodeCount*nodeCount; i++)
    {
        edgeList.push_back(graphNode());
        edgeList[i].value = infinity;
        edgeList[i].isInfinity = true;
        edgeList[i].pred = -1;
    }

    //Putting data from the file into the vector array
    while(!input.eof())
    {
        input >> row; //For each cycle through the list, we grab the first number on the line to get which x value (start vertex) we're working with
        while(input.peek() != '\n' && !input.eof())
        {
            input >> col;
            input >> edgeList[((row-1)*nodeCount)+(col-1)].value;
            edgeList[((row-1)*nodeCount)+(col-1)].isInfinity = false;
            edgeList[((row-1)*nodeCount)+(col-1)].pred = row;
            cout << row << ": " << " " << col << ": " << edgeList[((row-1)*nodeCount)+(col-1)].value << endl;
        }

    }
    input.close(); //Closing our input file since we don't need it anymore
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the numbers you spit out, it's clear this condition never evaluates to false until the end of the file:

`input.peek() != '\n' && !input.eof()`

My question to you is - are you using windows style, unix style or mac style line endings? And is there perhaps a better way to figure out where lines end that doesn't rely on assuming they take on a certain ASCII value(s)?

Comment: I'm not sure what style of line ending is being used. Input is copied from my instructor's site and saved in windows using geany. I could use getline or something similar, but the code is copied from a prior assignment where it worked. The only difference is the input lines were in numeric order (vertex 1, then vertex 2, etc)

Comment: @Ron Holcomb Download notepad++, View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters. Also, Edit -> EOL Conversion.

Comment: maybe try( ( input.peek( ) != '\n' ) || ( input.peek( ) != '\r' ) )

Comment: @Patashu The ends of my lines appear to be windows style by default, each line is ended by CRLF (the CR and the LF are in their own little black blocks).

Comment: @RonHolcomb Try putting a print statement at the end of the inner loop that prints the integer of the ASCII value of the value of `peek`

Comment: Ah hah, it was the end of line characters.  Somehow, my input from my last assignment was using Unix style, while this one was using Windows style.  Using input.peek() != '\r' catches it when it's using Windows style as well as Unix style.  Thank you very much for your help gents.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to read a line is to actually read the line.

```
std::string  line;
std::getline(input, line);
```

You can then parse the numbers out of the line.

```
std::stringstream linestream(line);
int node;
linestream >> node;

int dst, weight;
while(linestream >> dst >> weight)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

You should be careful:

```
while(!input.eof())
```

This is an anti-pattern. You have to be careful as if the stream goes into an error state the test will never become true and thus potentially leaving you in an infinite loop.

So your code should look like this:

```
int linesToRead;
input >> linesToRead;    

std::string  line;
for(;std::getline(input, line) && linesToRead;--linesToRead)
{
    // If there is a chance of an empty line
    // you may want to check here.

    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    int node;
    linestream >> node;

    int dst, weight;
    while(linestream >> dst >> weight)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Manually closing the file is not good practice.

```
input.close();
```

Potentially the streams can be set to throw on error. What happens if you call close() and it throws? Even if you are in normal mode and it just generates an error on close(). What are you planning on doing?  Best to let the destructor close the file and handle the error conditions for you. see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/544/507)